# Jquery Array key values with 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to make an array that looks like this:

```
Array = [A:{key:value,key:value},B:{key:value,key:value}]
```

But I have to add elements dynamically and I need to access them, how can I do this? ... Thanks For helping

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)?

Comment: " dynamically  " i will do that in a loop

Comment: Okay, I've added an answer which you could call in a loop to set or retrieve your values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since arrays resize automatically, you could do something pretty simple, like this (a and b are your row and column 'coordinates', respectively):

```
var myArray = [];
function save(a, b, value) {
    var row = myArray[a];
    if (!row) row = [];
    row[b] = value;
    myArray[a] = row;
};
function retrieve(a, b) {
    var row = myArray[a];
    return row ? row[b] : null;
};
```

Comment: what should i send to retrieve ? index numbers or specified name of the key

Comment: The way I wrote it, you'd send array row and column numbers. Eg: myValue = retrieve (3, 6). You could edit your question to add more explanation and/or detail, to get better answers. I assumed you wanted to store data in a two-dimensional array. You could just use an object instead, if you wanted to use a string key to retrieve your values.

Answer (score 0):

This will create what I think you want :

```
var arr = [
           {
             'A' : [
                   { 'key1' : 'value1' }, 
                   { 'key2' : 'value2' }
                  ] 
           }, 
           {
             'B' : [
                   { 'key1' : 'value1' }, 
                   { 'key2' : 'value2' }
                  ] 
           }
         ];
```

*Explanation* : Here, 'arr' is basically an array of objects with 2 objects with keys 'A'/'B' and values as array of 2 more objects. *(It's a little confusing)*